# I stayed on the Schengen area for 180 days with a visitor's residence permit. Can I leave and re-enter as a tourist within a day?

Tags: 90-180-visa-rules

I entered the Schengen area on March 25 and before the 90-day period expired I applied for a visitor's residenced permit that allowed me 90 extra days. If I go to the UK before August 23 for a week and come back, will they see it as a new 180-day period since I actually entered on March 25 or does the fact that I got those extra 90 days with a visitor residence permit change the 180-day period rule?

Comment: Basically, any days when the residence permit was valid don't count toward the 90-day total.  (Strictly speaking, that is only true for days you spent in the territory of the country that issued the permit.)  Since August is only 5 months after March, however, the answer to your question depends on the validity dates of the residence permit, which you have not disclosed.